# Flat FILE to XML and vica versa

Tags: xml, file, abap, idoc

I want to convert an IDOC flat file to XML. Then after making changes I have to convert that again to Flat file.
Is there any function module or class in ABAP using which I can do this.

Comment: Take a look at transaction XSLT_TOOL.  You will have to create the XSLT transformations yourself, and then call them using the statement "CALL TRANSFORMATION"

Answer (score 0):

Use FM `IDOC_XML_TRANSFORM` for this simple task.
Another approach can be used if you have not yet processed IDoc but want to process them directly in XML. Then you can use ALE Interface convertion like this:

1. Send an outbound IDOC data to a flat file (XML). You should do corresponding customizing on Sender for this: port, distribution model, partner profile.
2. Process the IDoc on the Receiver system.

If you want to do further changes with this XML, then use XML transformations as [Esti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25687/esti) kindly recommended to you.